# App crash on pressing home button in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a project where I need to call a web service again and again on a screen. It works fine. But the app crash when somebody press Home button to minimize it or when the device lights get dim (after sometime if nobody touches the device). Is there any way to get rid out of this? Kindly advice.

Comment: @trojanfoe http://emclstcd.tk

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026316/app-crash-while-app-in-the-background-after-device-goes-to-sleep-mode)

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);

Comment: @H2CO3 I think you wanted to direct that comment to the OP, not to me.  I understand what's required in order to elicit help...

Comment: @trojanfoe I meant to make that comment as a kind of "yeah, I agree, and this is how I tend to communicate this requirement towards the asker".

Comment: @H2CO3 OK cool.  I don't understand how so many people think problems can be solved without detail!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this variable:

u set bool variable no in info.plist file 
like

[image]